# Reading from a VM queue in Mule to send Emails in a EmailingService

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, queue, mule

I am working on an restful webservice, where the puropose of the webservice is to send out emails based on the request coming in.

We have decided to use Mule to achieve this. We have defined a flow in mule, which accepts the request(POST) and then writes it to a queue. Then there would be another flow which would read from this queue and then send out the messages using sendmail or any other java mail api.

I am responsible to create a flow which would read from the queue and then sends emails. Below is the mule_config.xml flow which writes messages to the queue:

```
   <!-- This is the persistent VM connector -->
   <vm:connector name="mailQueueConnector" queueTimeout="1000">
         <vm:queue-profile>
        <file-queue-store />
         </vm:queue-profile>
   </vm:connector>


    <flow name="MailService">
        <https:inbound-endpoint address="https://localhost:71234/message/email"
            method="POST"
            exchange-pattern="request-response"
            contentType="application/xml"/>

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="mailQueue" connector-ref="mailQueueConnector">
            <message-property-filter pattern="http.status=200" />
            <logger message="INTO mailQueue" level="INFO"/>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>
        <response>
            <message-property-filter pattern="http.status=200" />
            <script:transformer>
                <script:script engine="groovy">
                    <script:text>
                        import groovy.xml.*
                        def writer = new StringWriter()
                        def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
                        xml.ApiMessage {
                            returnCode("200")
                            reason("Queued Succesfully!!!")
                        }
                        return writer.toString()
                    </script:text>
                </script:script>
            </script:transformer>
        </response>
    </flow>
```

I can see from the above that POST email request that hits inbound endpoint "https://localhost:71234/message/email" is written into a queue "mailQueue". But for my task, how do i read email message that is in the queue and serialize it to an email object so that I can code in java to send that email? I assume that I have to write a new flow for that. Am I right? and could anybody please point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new flow with:

- A `vm:inbound-endpoint` that consumes the `mailQueue` path.
- Optionally a transformer to prepare the mail body.
- An `smtp:outbound-endpoint` that sends email messages, using MEL expressions for its different properties (to, subject...).

EDIT - The OP now wants the flow to be accessible both externally over HTTP and internally. Added a composite source to do that:

```
<flow name="emailer">
    <composite-source>
        <https:inbound-endpoint address="localhost:71234/message/sendEmail"
            method="POST" exchange-pattern="request-response"
            contentType="application/xml" />
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="mailQueue"
            connector-ref="mailQueueConnector">
    </composite-source>
    <!-- Add transformers here if needed -->
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint ... />
</flow>
```

Comment: As I am planning to have a rest endpoint(post), which would have the code to send email using sendmail, would it be better to have an http:outbound-endpoint like this: <https:inbound-endpoint address="https://localhost:71234/message/sendEmail"
   method="POST"
   exchange-pattern="request-response"
   contentType="application/xml"/>

Comment: Then I would add a VM endpoint alongside the HTTP one, in a composite source, in the "emailer" flow and would call it internally over VM. No need to use HTTP when in memory calls would do.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand that. Could you please show me the flow of what you meant. Thanks

Comment: I've added a flow example that uses a composite source so you can see how it works.